# highlighted cells not aligned anymore

Tags: tables, siunitx

Cells 421 and 237 (in this example) are not aligned when one of them is highlighted in any way (bold, colored etc.). I only used S columns where necessary. Here is a small example:

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{tabu, longtable}


\begin{document}


\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {X[2, l]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]S[table-format=4]X[c]}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{column1}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{column2}} \\
                    & a & b                                & c & d & e & f \\
    \textbf{round1} & 2.876 & 22                           & 5.837 & 2.433 & \textbf{421} & 5.235 \\
           &        &       &                              & 6.564 & 4.434 & 237 & 1.345 \\

\end{longtabu}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is package `siunitx` missing. Add currly braces arround the `e` in the second row, add `detect-weight` to the settings of `S` and use

```
\protected\bfseries 421
```

to align the bold `421`:

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{tabu, longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {X[2, l]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]S[table-format=4,detect-weight]X[c]}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{column1}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{column2}} \\
                    & a & b                                & c & d & {e} & f \\
    \textbf{round1} & 2.876 & 22                           & 5.837 & 2.433 & \protected\bfseries 421 & 5.235 \\
                    &       &                              & 6.564 & 4.434 & 237 & 1.345 \\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Unfortunaly it seems that `\color` does not work in a `S` column with `tabu`. But you can use `\tablenum`:

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\tablenum[table-format=4,color=orange]{421}}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{tabu, longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {X[2, l]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]S[table-format=4,detect-weight]X[c]}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{column1}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{column2}} \\
                    & a & b                                & c & d & {e} & f \\
    \textbf{round1} & 2.876 & 22                           & 5.837 & 2.433 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tablenum[table-format=4,color=orange]{421}} & 5.235 \\
                    &       &                              & 6.564 & 4.434 & 237 & 1.345 \\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

---

Or

```
\multicolumn{1}{>{\cellcolor{gray}}c}{\tablenum[table-format=4,color=orange]{421}}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{tabu, longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\specSc{}
\def\specSc#1[#2]#3{%
  \multicolumn{1}{>{#1}c}{\tablenum[#2]{#3}}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to .5\textwidth {X[l]S[table-format=4.1]S[table-format=1.3,detect-weight]}
& {e} & {f} \\
\textbf{round1}
  & \specSc{\bfseries}[table-format=4.1,detect-weight]{421.3} 
  & 5.235 \\
& \specSc{\color{orange}}[table-format=4.1]{237}
  & \specSc{}[table-format=1.3,color=purple]{1.34} \\
& \specSc{\cellcolor{lightgray}}[table-format=4.1,color=blue]{237.2}
  & \protected\bfseries 1.342 \\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]